# Excel VBA - Runtime error '1004'

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have some VBA code where I want to copy a formula into a range of cells using `R1C1`. Unfortunately I get the following error on the second to last line: 
`Runtime error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.`

```
Dim pct As Single
pct = 1

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").UsedRange
    Dim lastR As Long
    lastR = .Rows.Count 
    Dim lastC As String
    lastC = col_letter(.Columns.Count)
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Calculations")
    .Range("A1:" & lastC & 1).Value = 100
==> .Range("A2:" & lastC & lastR + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C*(1+" & pct / 100 & "*'Data'!R[-1]C"
End With
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what are your `lastC` and `lastR` current values when error occurs?

Comment: ``lastC`` = "CU";
``lastR``= 1000;
``pct``= 0.1

Comment: do you know the difference between using & and + in VBA? its is probably the path to you file data and extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are running non-english version of Excel/Office. Therefore there could be a problem of numbers separation mark. It's required to use `. (dot)` in function defined as string and passed then by `formulaR1C1 property` to Excel. It will be then converted into `, (comma)` which is required when putting function in excel cell. Therefore this lines works for me with no error:

```
....=Replace("=R[-1]C*(1+" & pct / 100 & ")*Data!R[-1]C", ",", ".")
```

One more thing, I removed `'' (single quotation marks)` for sheet name.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help - I think KazJaw's suggestion finally solved the problem.

Comment: UPDATE: I just changed the regional settings of my operating system to 'United States'. Now I can use any function without problems and don't even have to use ``replace``.

Answer (score 2):

you're missing a parenthesis in the formula-perhaps

```
"=R[-1]C*(1+" & pct / 100 & ")*'Data'!R[-1]C"
```

Comment: You're right, I was missing a parenthesis. But the runtime error is still occurring on the same line...

Comment: what if you do the calculation in the formula `"=R[-1]C*(1+" & pct & "/100)*'Data'!R[-1]C"`

Comment: does the formula return errors if you enter it manually into those cells? (does data!A1 contain a number?)